# Using Authorization Header in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authorization

Im a total noob and I'm just beginning to learn about APIs. I'm trying to use the Yelp API and I cant seem to access it. 
According to the documentation, I'm supposed to: "Put the API Key in the request header as "Authorization: Bearer "
I'm not familiar with Authorizations and Not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Here's what I have

```
    function displayYelp() {
  var URL =
    "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=restaurant&latitude=40.82783908257346&longitude=-74.10162448883057";

  $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      authorization:
        "bearer //My Key Goes Here",
    },
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Even if you can't answer my specific question, Any help on what Authorization means would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you run this code, do you get data back from the API? If so, you're doing it correctly.  The code above looks fine.  You're passing `Authorization: bearer [your API bearer token]` as an HTTP header with your request to the server.  The server will respond with an error message and HTTP code other than 2xx if there's an issue with your request.  [The RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750) is not what I would call light reading but it should contain everything you need to know about the OAuth bearer token authentication.

Comment: [Вадим Джамиев](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10859969/Вадим-Джамиев) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570289/12695027) saying "..this is solution for your last problem: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your comment that you are having issues with the preflight.  The reason the API request is being blocked during preflight is because Yelp isn't sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  Because they don't send this header, you will not be able to make a cross-origin AJAX request.

After searching GitHub, I've found several sources supporting the fact that the Yelp API doesn't support client-side JavaScript because of CORS security issues:

[CORS issue Fetch API cannot load https://api.yelp.com #25](https://github.com/olalonde/node-yelp/issues/25#issuecomment-275943882)

[Does api.yelp.com support Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for client-side JS? #99](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/issues/99#issuecomment-187406811)

This means you'll need to use a server-side approach to use the API.  Disclaimer: I've seen mentions of a JSONP approach but have yet to find a working example.

Comment: Thanks so much! Again I'm a beginner so I'll need to do some more research to even understand how to do that lol. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The `Authorization` header is frequently used to authenticate to an API using a token. You can read more about token authentication [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/). You might want to try adding an error handler so you can see what the problem is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: URL,
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Authorization":
      "Bearer //My Key Goes Here",
  },
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

You may also need to capitalize "Authorization" and "Bearer" in order to have the correct header format. Otherwise, your ajax call looks correct!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got this message: "Failed to Load: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."  Does this mean I have the wrong key or something?